# How to automatically add 2 spaces for every enter in Markdown document in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I hate the markdown rule of newline/break not treated as newline. If I can change that rule for my personal .md use I will use it. I use md predominantly for personal note and that rule makes .md artificially ugly and hard to use for me (when i copy paste from other sources for instance).

Do vscode has an extension that automatically add 2 spaces padding to every new line? It's not an elegant solution but at least it's better than manually adding it and slows down the note taking process.

Comment: Is [code-fencing](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks) no use to you?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I use code-fencing for code snippets in my note. My note taking system is vscode with markdown files (similar to how people use evernote / onenote). Everything is nice but when I convert the note into pdf using extension, my notes became very ugly because of the enter is not real enter thingy. Of couse I can solve the problem already with double space ending, but I ask the community if anyone know of a more elegant solution

Comment: i'd be interested in a more elegant solution too ..

Answer (score -1):

I published a tiny extension to

- Automatically updating a "date modified" in the note YAML header (lastmod, modified)
- Automatically adding 2 spaces at the end of lines on saving

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Huka.blogging-tool
You can find it on Visual studio, by typing `Huka` on Extensions tab.

Could you give it a try?

Comment: Does it add spaces at the end of sentences or end of lines?

Comment: @fpnick Thank you for pointing it out. I edited it.